# Azure Devops Release pipeline causing Service Connection Error

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am attempting to create a release pipeline in Azure devops to deploy an api.

When I attempt to authorize the deployment stage, I get the error below. Doesn't have any information that really helps to solve. Any advice is appreciated. I am the Owner on the subscription.

[image: Error in Azure devops]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably try navigating to the **Project settings -> Service Connections -> New Service Connection -> Azure Resource Manager** and create a service principle based connection from there.
This looks more like an internal application error to me since Azure DevOps hasn't given any error details to use for troubleshooting.

If that doesn't work either than you can try manually creating a service principle from Azure and setting the credentials in Azure DevOps for connecting to ARM. But keep this one for the worst case.

Comment: Thanks Varun, this solved the issue i.e. setting up azure resource manager manually. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should try providing all the details regarding the Azure subscription you're trying to connect to and then link service principal.
You can do that by clicking "connect to Azure" being displayed in blue colour inside the error message

Comment: Thanks Nilansh, I tried your suggestion but same error.

Comment: John, did you try to reconnect by inputting the details including service principal secret and client ID?

Comment: All good Nilansh, response below solved it. thanks for your help